# If an IOException in Java is thrown by isReachable, what would be an appropriate action to take and why?

Tags: java, ioexception

If an IOException in Java is thrown by isReachable, what would be an appropriate action to take and why?

I guess the answer is the program should terminate the operation and print system message: the host is not reachable. Because isReachable throws IOException means the host is not reachable.
But I am not sure about the answer. If you could help me, I will be so thankful.

thank you so much

Comment: I assume you're talking about [InetAddress#isReachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable(int))? It's best to be specific about these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct answer depends on your application. A return value of `false` is usually what you'd expect from a failure to contact the host in question, while `IOException` indicates a nebulous "network error", which means something like the OS indicated an unusual network problem. Now that you know that there's a bigger issue than the other host being down, the action to take might be to pop up an error dialog for a graphical application, or to exit with a non-zero return code for a CLI one. You have to decide what the user should see when that happens and whether the application should go into some sort of offline mode (like Firefox) or abort (like `wget`).